# Rewrite rule with + in old url using nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I am moving a bunch of photos that were hosted with Gallery2 to a new subdomain hosted by Zenfolio. I am trying to make some redirects from the old domain to the new one for more popular photo albums. Unfortunately, G2 uses + in album names with spaces and Nginx does not seem to be redirecting those to the proper place.

Here's an example config I'm using. Any assistance is appreciated!

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
    listen   [::]:80; ## listen for ipv6

keepalive_timeout   70;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name old.domain.com;
    root /var/www/old.domain.com/public_html;
    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html

        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules

rewrite /photos/2013+example+race/ http://photos.domain.com/13-example-race permanent;

try_files $uri @404_redirect;
}

location @404_redirect {
    return 301 http://photos.domain.com;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a regular expression, `+` has a meaning (repeats 1 or more times), so you should try to escape the `+`

```
rewrite /photos/2013\+example\+race/ http://photos.domain.com/13-example-race permanent;
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm so embarrassed, I sort was going to try that and just figured it wouldn't work since no quick googling mentioned it.